# Editing Emmet abbreviations in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

In Visual Studio Code, whenever I click "." (dot) and Enter, the editor replaces it with

```
<div class=""></div>
```

When Caps Lock is on, it opens the "Emmet: Expand Abbreviation" command. I want to disable both these behaviors: "." should just click "." with nothing else. How can I do this?

Comment: Where you say you 'click "."' do you mean you are **typing** the `.` and then hitting `Enter`?  For me that results in `<div className=""></div>`.

Comment: @Mark yes, this is what I meant. I would like to disable this behavior.

Comment: Do you get `<div className=""></div>` when you do that?

Comment: @Mark yes, sorry, the "div" was invisible in the question - fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are out of luck, I remember this issue:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87985 (Edit/remove specific emmet abbreviation (dot expands to empty div))

The issue was closed `as designed`.  You could remove the <kbd>Enter</kbd> as an acceptance trigger, via this Setting:

`Editor: Accept Suggestion on Enter`  // set to `never`

so that only <kbd>Tab</kbd> would replace with the emmet abbreviation and <kbd>Enter</kbd> would insert a newline.